# Undefined variable for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a code in use and it generates a PHP error in the second "for" loop.

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: newmatches

```
            if (empty($result['ERR'])) {
                preg_match_all('(<h3><a[^<>]*href="([^<>]*)"[^<>]*>(.*)</a>\s*</h3>)siU', $result['EXE'], $matches);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
                    $matches[1][$i] = urldecode($matches[1][$i]);
                    preg_match_all('/\*\*(http:\/\/.*$)/siU', $matches[1][$i], $urls);
                    $newmatches[1][$i] = $urls[1][0];
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($newmatches[1]); $i++) {  //PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: newmatches 
                if(strstr($newmatches[1][$i], $domain))
                    return $i+1;
                }
            } else {
                return '0';
            }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check if the first loop is ever run…

Comment: $newmatches is a local variable to the `for` loop. Initialize it before if( ). `$newmatches = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where $newmatches would be set, aside from the first for loop, which won't run if count($matches[1]) is 0.

Not sure what all this hardcoding of your index to 1 is about, but a simple fix is to set `$newmatches[1] = array()` before the first loop.

Comment: thank you very much! 
public function SERPYahooKeyowrdPostion($domain_name, $title). Works fine!